# Argument vs Angle in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Apologies if this is an elementary question (and for the lengthy post!), as I'm new to complex analysis.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the angle function $\angle\colon\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to[0;\pi]$ is often defined as
$$\angle(x,y)=\arccos\left(\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}\right)$$
with standard inner product (dot product) and norm. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example, we have
$$\angle((x,y),(u,v))=\arccos\left(\frac{\langle (x,y),(u,v) \rangle}{\|(x,y)\|\|(u,v)\|}\right)=\arccos\left(\frac{xu+yv}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2)}}\right).$$
In particular the angle between $(x,y)$ and the positive $x$-axis is
$$\angle((x,y),(1,0))=\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)=\angle((x,-y),(1,0)).$$
On the other hand the (principal) argument $\operatorname{Arg}\colon\mathbb{C}\to(-\pi,\pi]$ also denotes the angle between $z$ and the positive real axis, but "signed" in the sense that $\operatorname{Arg}z<0$ whenever $y<0$. If all of this is correct, is it appropriate to write
$$\operatorname{Arg}(x+iy)=\begin{cases}
\angle((x,y),(1,0)), &y\geq 0\\
-\angle((x,y),(1,0)), &y<0
\end{cases}$$
in general? I assume not, because the piecewise definition I've seen is much more complicated and involves $\arctan$, but what goes wrong?

Comment: Did you mean $- \angle((x,y),(1,0)), \quad y<0$?

Comment: @L.F. Yep, sorry! Edited.

Comment: Nothing goes wrong. I think $\text{arctan}$ is used just by tradition. That's not the only case where historic influences are unfortunate in Mathematics.

Comment: When your method of calculating is by looking up values in a set of tables (something I am just old enough to have been taught how to do), you want to do as few of those look-ups as possible. Division is easy enough to do by hand. so the arctan formula requires only one table look-up, but the arccos formula requires two multiplications and an addition on top of the division, and most significantly, a second table look-up to get the square root. Before the invention of computers, arctan was definitely the easier choice, even if it did involve more cases.